# UE4: How to make UProceduralMeshComponent a solid body, not just a surface around volume?

Tags: collision-detection, procedural-generation, unreal-4, mesh

I generated the UProceduralMeshComponent and set collision enabled to ECollisionEnabled::QueryOnly.

But I get ActorEndOverlapEvent if I stop touching the mesh border even if I still inside of mesh body. So, how to make it solid to get this event only if I left from the mesh volume (like in ATriggerBox for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.

First of all, I need to turn off option "Use Complex as Simple Collision"

```
bUseComplexAsSimpleCollision = false;
```

and then I can add simple collision convex hulls:

```
// Create collision simple mesh
for (const TArray<FVector>& Hull : ConvexHulls)
{
    ShapeMesh->AddCollisionConvexMesh(Hull);
}
```

I added few hulls because my shape can be a concave polygon based, so, I need to split it to few convex polygons and add volume for each separately.